# Interactive Tree Builder

Tags: classification, software-recommendation

Where can I find a download link for the Interactive Tree Builder: https://orange.readthedocs.io/en/latest/widgets/rst/classify/interactivetreebuilder.html ?

It is not available on the documentation though the menu.

Thanks
Rick

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept it (click on the green tick)

Answer (score 1):

The link you sent seems to be old/outdated documentation.

This is the latest up-to-date version of Orange: https://orangedatamining.com/

You can download it here: https://orangedatamining.com/download/

Comment: Hi Adam. The link is for the documentation. I cant find the add-on download link and it doesnot apper at the apps menu.

Comment: Hi @RicardoSilva, have you clicked my second link. You can download it from there.